# openapi-generator how to generate a c-sharp .NET core 3.1 compatible test in my solution's MS Test project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a .net-core 3.1 solution with a simple endpoint accepting only a post. I want to use openAPI-generator to generate the SDK (because the New REST Client SDK option is not available in *visual studio for mac*).

The first time I did this, I did it with the command:

```
openapi-generator generate -i ../swagger.v0.0.21.json -g csharp -o ./generator
```

this generated a .net framework solution, so I had to hack it a bit and install some nuget test libraries to get it to run at all. I was getting connection refused after all that -- which I hope is just related to the fact that it was built for the wrong framework.

I'm noticing there is another generate target, *csharp-netcore*. I'm not sure how to use it though. What should my command look like? I was thinking:

```
openapi-generator generate -i ../swagger.v0.0.21.json -g csharp-netcore -targetFramework netcoreapp3.1 -o ./generator
```

but that yields:

```
[error] Found unexpected parameters: [netcoreapp3.1]
```

(just to be explicit, I have a solution structure:

- Assignment_1/

  - Assignment_1_Tests/

and it is in that that I would like to do my testing. but my source is directly off of the Assignment_1 directory.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `--additional-properties=targetFramework=netcoreapp3.1`

Source: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/#additional-properties